# Why are interface method implementations with differing intersection type arguments allowed?

Tags: typescript

I have a very simple interface and implementation, like this:

```
class Transform {
  X: number = 0
  Y: number = 0
}
class RenderData {
  Model: object | null = null
}

interface System {
  Update(e: Transform & RenderData): void
}

class RenderSystem implements System {
  Update(e: RenderData): void {
    // Why is this allowed?
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOYB2EBmB7eBbaBvAUNNABoBc0SArlgEYCm80AvNAAyHQCa5VtDzbfAF98oSDABKdJABMGAETAAXMHg4BZdHJDl0NAFZ1gS6AB8KlECAFUrw-PgCWSJQ1RhgdaAGUAnhFccAiIAVQAHGWU6AAo6cgRkNEwcADJoKVkFZTAASnIAN3RHGXtRcCh06Tl4PwC6HEcsMJB66SUYWsC1UIio2PIM6sUVPOhC4u6iaAB6aegAdQALX2hHGCVFtegwK3QAdzoZAH4OEREy8UrMmv9AgCZVppasNo7b+snwyNd+iz54UbjGR4GZzAA8TEh0AAovB4JhtjA6AAPMJGVwlIhnfBAA)

I would have expected an error here, as if I had replaced `Update(e: RenderData)` with something like `Update(e: number)`. That wouldn't implement the interface, and TSC would complain. So why is this allowed with an incomplete intersection type?

Comment: Interesting. Looks like Update will take any object as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is the intended behavior, and it is type safe.  Just to be clear about what's happening, I am going to rewrite your types to use function-valued properties (of the form `foo: ()=>void`) instead of methods (of the form `foo(): void`), and we will use [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types):

```
interface System {
  Update: (e: Transform & RenderData) => void
}

class RenderSystem implements System {
  Update = (e: RenderData) => { } // okay
}

class BadRenderSystem implements System {
  Update = (e: number) => { } // error!
  //  Type 'Transform & RenderData' is not assignable to type 'number'
}
```

---

The sort of type safety we generally care about is known as [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); so `X` is a subtype of `Y` if and only if a value of type `X` can freely be used wherever a value of type `Y` is wanted.  If someone asks for a `Y` and you can substitute in a value of type `X` without them noticing, then `X` is a subtype of `Y`.

This type safety requires that function types be [*contravariant*](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in the types of their parameters.  So the type `((e: X) => void)` is a subtype of `((e: Y) => void)` if and only if `X` is a *supertype* of `Y`.  That is, the subtype relationship between function types *varies* in the opposite way (or *counter* to) that of the types of the parameters.

And TypeScript does enforce type safety this way (at least for non-method types with `--strictFunctionTyes` enabled).

---

That means `RenderSystem` is fine because the type of its `Update` parameter, `RenderData` is a *supertype* of the `Update` parameter of `System`, which is `Transform & RenderData`.

You can verify that this makes sense via substitutability above.  Let's imagine I ask for a `System` and you hand me a value, `system`.  It turns out that `system` is of the type `RenderSystem`, but I don't know that.  I'm going to treat it like it's a `System`.  So I take my value `e` of type `Transform & RenderData` and call `system.Update(e)`.  Does that work?  Well, `RenderSystem`'s `Update` method requires that its input be a `RenderData`.  Since `e` is both a `Transform` and a `RenderData` (that's what [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) mean; `X & Y` is both a subtype of `X` and a subtype of `Y`), anything `RenderSystem.Update` wants to do with `e` will be fine.  Everyone is happy, and `RenderSystem implements System`.

Compare that to what happens when you hand me a `BadRenderSystem` value.  Now when I call `system.Update(e)`, the `BadRenderSystem` instance takes that `e` input and treats it as if it were a `number`.  Does that work? No, in general, a `Transform & RenderData` cannot be used like a `number`.  If `BadRenderSystem.Update` wants to call `e.toFixed(2)`, for example, bad things will happen.  So `BadRenderSystem` is *not* subtitutable for `System`.

So everything is as it should be here.

This is the end of the answer to the question as asked, although you may wonder why I rewrote the types above.

---

Now it turns out that TypeScript does allow some unsafe behavior with method implementations.  If you turn off `--strictFunctionTypes` (don't do that), or leave it on and use methods instead of function properties, TypeScript will also accept method types to vary in the *same* direction as their parameters... that is, *covariantly*.  So TypeScript checks method parameter inputs *both* covariantly *and* contravariantly, which is also called checking [*bivariantly*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).  Method parameters are allowed to be either supertypes *or subtypes* of the methods they extend or implement.

Bivariant type checking of parameters is *not* type safe, but it is convenient.  You can read about why it is done [in the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) (or clicking the "bivariantly" link above).

It doesn't have any direct bearing on your example code, but if we tried this with the above strictly checked function properties, you'd get an error:

```
class UnsafeRenderSystem implements System {
  Update = (e: RenderData & Transform & Date) => { } // error!
}
```

It isn't safe for the compiler to assume that the `e` passed in is also a `Date`, so it errors.  When we go back to methods:

```
interface System {
  Update(e: Transform & RenderData): void
}

class RenderSystem implements System {
  Update(e: RenderData) { }
}

class BadRenderSystem implements System {
  Update(e: number) { } // error!
  //  Type 'Transform & RenderData' is not assignable to type 'number'
}

class UnsafeRenderSystem implements System {
  Update(e: RenderData & Transform & Date) { } // okay
}
```

we see that while `BadRenderSystem` is still prohibited (`number` being neither a supertype nor a subtype of `RenderData & Transform`), the `UnsafeRenderSystem` is *allowed* now because of bivariant checking (`RenderData & Transform & Date` is a subtype of `RenderData & Transform`).

So you may want to keep that in mind.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxArseAFATgexiiQG8AoUpJeAGxCiIBUcRgoAzPHMEiypADQBcSYGjAAjCDiQBeJAAZelAJrDREqbIW8Avrxp0iAJQjAAJlIAiIAC4gefJAFk8F6sLziAVhHg2kAD4iaNTUWqKhuuSUAJbANlJsCMgAygCeUAncZI4AqjBmthDCABTFSEws7JzcAGRIJuZWtiAAlLIAfEgAbngxZlH6tPQNphY46ZkQ3DFgMNTTpjZEk1kOfPmFCVplwo3j1nbtMl3ESHqUekOGSABCIGb7UqvTSLPzi-ErGWs5GwVFHbldSSHDHU7nJAAeihSCk+BwAEIlNDYRU0jBkABySqsDhcJD1J44Q4gLFvIjAPD+QwxADmoHECyQNjwLIx2JBUixg0oBhGuVYIDYEGJLxmcwWkC+SHF60om0Bcl2oyaJJahIqzDxNU1hwg4JIkJhcJwCORl3IV1AkFgyWcEBsAAtXEQyNcRrjqgS-pQhMENNI5IpHKoA6CtCHzh7jGNmnZ5c5XBB3EhPD4-IFgqFwiFqLy3vFEva5b6kIqEiqvfi6qqDi1WsJev0C-zY2q5e8pUtvlNsiiKxAVcTSe0zhdozG7g8xT9Xl3PstZXP+3kAZXgWJQWPjbD4ZwLXwTejMUgcdrvbWRy1yTFKdSkLSGSAmchWezT1iuTgeZap4KoGFUU4wmFc3klRde1+Ad1yHcprwTepq11ep9R3HRUTTABrEA0kGHQgA)

Comment: Great explanation. Out of curiosity, is there a clean way to get type-safe methods that use the class prototype? It looks like function properties are added to each class instance when compiled. The only strategy I can think of would be to declare a separate interface then build the class separately using `MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function (...)` syntax.

Comment: Actually as long as the interface you implement has function-property syntax, the classes can use real prototype methods and the compiler will still complain about unsafe implementations, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXkJkW).